# Issues mounting hostPath in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Alright, I'm trying to set up a local version of a Jenkins container in kubernetes' minikube and I was using [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-container-engine-tutorial) as a model.

The problem that I'm having is that the hostPath does not seem to be mounting correctly.

When I try to mount the host path without using a "persistentVolumeClaim"
my code looks like this:

**deployment_jenkins.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: master
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: master
        image: jenkins:2.7.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 50000
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /login
            port: 8080
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 2
          failureThreshold: 5
        env:
        - name: JENKINS_OPTS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: jenkins
              key: options
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
          name: jenkins-home
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1500Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1500Mi
      volumes:
      - name: jenkins-home
      hostPath:
        path: /data
```

and I get this error when I run *kubectl apply-f deployment_jenkins.yaml*:

```
my-mac kubernetes $ kubectl apply -f deployment_jenkins.yaml
error: error validating "deployment_jenkins.yaml": error validating data: 
found invalid field hostPath for v1.PodSpec; if you choose to ignore these 
errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

and then when I try to use claims, I get this:

**persistent_volume_claim_jenkins.yaml**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-home-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeName: jenkins-home
```

**persistent_volume_jenkins.yaml**

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-home
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data
```

**deployment_jenkins.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: master
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: master
        image: jenkins:2.7.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 50000
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /login
            port: 8080
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 2
          failureThreshold: 5
        env:
        - name: JENKINS_OPTS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: jenkins
              key: options
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
          name: jenkins-home
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1500Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 1500Mi
      volumes:
      - name: jenkins-home
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jenkins-home-claim
```

And then I run the command:

```
my-mac kubernetes $ kubectl apply -f .
deployment "jenkins" configured
persistentvolumeclaim "jenkins-home-claim" configured
persistentvolume "jenkins-home" configured
```

And ultimately, my pod never spins up and I get these errors in the dashboard:
[image]

I'm super confused and any help in figuring out what I'm doing wrong and how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your yaml is mis-indented leading to a different (broken) interpretation:

`volumes:
      - name: jenkins-home
      hostPath:
        path: /data`

This is an object with two fields, `volumes` and `hostPath`.  What you want, instead, is:

`volumes:
      - name: jenkins-home
        hostPath:
          path: /data`

Also, I recommend always quoting (non-block) strings in your yaml to avoid surprises:

`volumes:
      - name: 'jenkins-home'
        hostPath:
          path: '/data'`

Comment: Success, I'm a little farther now :)  

Now I'm getting this error:
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log’: Permission denied


any chance you'd know how to get past that?

Comment: Sure.  Run your container with permissions to write to the filesystem you give it.  Perhaps use an init container to set up the filesystem in a suitable way.  It depends how the Jenkins container works.

Comment: Thanks, I marked your answer as the correct one. I never did quite get this to work the whole way because it started to become too painful to use a registry to pull my custom docker image (google cloud container registry auth permissions documents didn't quite work), so I skipped that part and push my new change out. but the double quotes totally fixed my first error. Thanks :)